# Number of Asymmetric, Balanced Permutation Matrices

Tags: matrices, permutations

let $\mathcal{ABP}$, the set of "*asymmetric*, *balanced* *permutation* *matrices*", be defined as the set of permutation matrices, that aren't equal their transpose but, for which the number $1$s below the principal diagonal equals the number of $1$s above that diagonal, i.e.:
$P\in\mathcal{ABP}\implies$ $$p_{ij}\in\{0,1\}\\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{ij}=1\\ \sum_{i<j}p_{ij}=\sum_{j<i}p_{ij}\\ P\ne P^T$$

> **Question:**
>   how many asymmetric, balanced permutation matrices exist for given dimension $n$?

(other information about those matrices or permutation is also appreciated.)

Comment: Note that all involutions are known (these are symmetric, and thus also balanced). You can then compute only balanced permutations, and then take the difference. The number of balanced permutations seems to be given by https://oeis.org/A010551

after a computer experiment...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson after some ruminating I believe that the balanced permutation matrices should correspond to permutations, for which the number of positive differences of adjacent elements equals that of the negative differences and, after some searching I found out that the number of such permutations are the Kendall-Mann numbers; they correspond to [oeis.org/A000140](http://oeis.org/A000140) and have been the subject of [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46368/the-property-of-kendall-mann-numbers) question. Sadly, I only found a recursive function for involutions.