# The growth of maximum elements for the reflection group $D_n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, coxeter-groups, weyl-group, reflection-groups

Let's consider maximum coefficients in Poincaré polynomial (or growth series) for the reflection group (or Weyl group, or finite Coxeter group) $D_n$ as mentioned in [A162206](http://oeis.org/A162206).
The maximal numbers $M(n)$: $1,2,6,30,212,1924,21280,...$

$\frac {6} {2} = 3$;

$\frac {30} {6} =5$;

$\frac {212} {30}=7,06666667$;

$\frac {1924} {212}=9,0754717$;

$\frac {21280} {1924}=11,0602911$

How to prove $\frac {M_{n+1}} {M_{n}} \approx 2n-1$ for large $n$?

I know that the similar ratio for row max of [Mahonian numbers](http://oeis.org/A008302) $T(n,k)$ yields $\approx n-\frac {1} {2}$ while the numbers form the [rank of the vector space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314429/why-triangle-of-mahonian-numbers-tn-k-forms-the-rank-of-the-vector-space) with the well known generating function for inversions.

Comment: This is now http://www.findstat.org/St001443.

Comment: I haven't thought this through to the end, but perhaps there is an argument based on writing the Poincare polynomials in terms of the degrees.  It is certainly easy to write a recursion giving the actual polynomials.  From there, maybe one can see how largest coefficients behave under the recursion.  Have you tried that?  UPDATE:  Based on the OEIS sequence you reference, I'm now guessing you've already thought about this.